# create firebase project operation has timed out

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

I am trying to create new firebase project, But after going through the steps, at the final yellow spinning progress it shows when creating, it freezes and shows `The operation has timed out. Please restart and try again` in red.

It actually creates the project in GCP, but it doesn't create it in firebase or show in the list.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**There was indeed an outage in project creation in the Firebase console, which is recovering as we speak. Some other Firebase services are experienced problems and are recovering. Check the [Firebase status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) for the latest status.**

---

As a workaround, you can click the <kbd>Add project</kbd> button again after the project shows up in the Google Cloud Console, and then select that project from the dropdown in Firebase:

[image: Selecting a GCP project in the Firebase console]

When I just did that on the project shown above, Firebase was added to it within 20 seconds.

---

Update 1: I noticed that the project in GCP was created only after something like 15 minutes, so I suspect the Firebase side of it gives up before that.

---

Update 2: We're putting a banner up on our status page right now to signal this problem, and problems in some other Firebase products that we suspect have the same root cause.

---

Update 3: We have a workaround for this specific use, which I documented above.

---

Update 4: The status for affected services is now reflected on the Firebase status page linked at the top.

In addition, the root problem seems to have been addressed, and the affected services are recovering and clearing out their backlog.